# XmlSerializer not serializing List

Tags: c#, .net-core, xml-serialization

I am having some bad luck serializing a list of objects.

here is the XML that I'm trying to serialize.

```
<Root version="1">
    <Elements>
        <Element>
            <Id>c5b9f5d9-0671-4769-8a3a-8e7ce06b889d</Id>
            <GroupId>c5b9f5d9-0671-4769-8a3a-8e7ce06b889d</GroupId>
            <Dwell>10</Dwell>
        </Element>
        <Element>
            <Id>67d3ffba-b405-4d1e-8dbb-ea21d0ba4e7b</Id>
            <GroupId>67d3ffba-b405-4d1e-8dbb-ea21d0ba4e7b</GroupId>
            <Dwell>10</Dwell>
        </Element>
        <Element>
            <Id>3b5d421d-3b93-461d-af77-d1b1e922a092</Id>
            <GroupId>3b5d421d-3b93-461d-af77-d1b1e922a092</GroupId>
            <Dwell>10</Dwell>
        </Element>
        <Element>
            <Id>a24e3fce-846c-45ec-8a08-79add8f9024e</Id>
            <GroupId>a24e3fce-846c-45ec-8a08-79add8f9024e</GroupId>
            <Dwell>10</Dwell>
        </Element>
    </Elements>
</Root>
```

Here are the classes that it's trying to sterilize to.

```
[XmlRoot("Root")]
    public class TourRoot:BaseXmlWriter
    {
        [XmlAttribute("version")]
        public int Version { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Elements")]
        public List<TourRootElement> Elements { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Element")]
    public class TourRootElement
    {
        [XmlElement("Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("GroupId")]
        public string GroupId { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Dwell")]
        public int Dwell { get; set; }
    }
```

here is the code that is trying to sterilize it.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TourRoot));
var reader = new StringReader(entity.XmlData);
var tour = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as TourRoot;
```

What's happening:
the sterilizer is creating the object, adding the correct value in the version property, creating the list, and only adding 1 element to the list with all default values, not the correct values. What's even stranger is when I take one of these elements and try to run a deserialize on it works correctly for that one object.

My Question:
Why does the list not populate correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out.

I needed to add a couple of attributes to the list.

```
    [XmlArray("Elements"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(TourRootElement), ElementName = "Element")]
    public List<TourRootElement> Elements { get; set; }
```